# jQuery Datatables plugin, Dynamically created last column Average on fnRowCallBack is not Sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So I use the `fnRowCallback` event to dynamically calculate and insert the average of the whole row in the last column called `Average`. The column is defined in the `json.aoColumns`. However, it is not sortable. Is there anyway to make it sortable? It shows the sort icon but when I click on it it doesn't do anything but changing the sort icon.

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                        var iRowTotal = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < aaData.length - 2; i++) {
                            if (aaData[i + 2] != "")
                                iRowTotal += parseInt(aaData[i + 2], 10);
                        }
                        iRowTotal = parseFloat(iRowTotal / (aaData.length - 3)).toFixed(2);
                        lastColumn = aaData.length - 1;
                        $('td:eq(' + lastColumn + ')', nRow).html(iRowTotal);

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTables does not magically updates its internal structures when you inject data to the DOM. You must go through dataTables own methods, like [`fnUpdate`](http://datatables.net/ref#fnUpdate). I also suggest you use the `fnCreatedRow` callback instead of `fnRowCallback` because `fnRowCallback` not provides the real row index.

Here is an example inserting a random number in the last column :

```
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    fnCreatedRow: function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        this.fnUpdate(randomNumber, iDataIndex, 4);
    }
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vYyFv/** ..Your code would look something like this (not tested)

```js
fnCreatedRow: function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
     var iRowTotal = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < aaData.length - 2; i++) {
         if (aaData[i + 2] != "") iRowTotal += parseInt(aaData[i + 2], 10);
     }
     iRowTotal = parseFloat(iRowTotal / (aaData.length - 3)).toFixed(2);
     var lastColumn = aaData.length - 1;
     this.fnUpdate(iRowTotal, iDataIndex, lastColumn);
}
```

Note, the fiddle above is dataTables v1.9.4.